# passing a newline in commandline parameter in c#

Tags: c#, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have a console application with some arguments to be passed.

"c:\My Folder\myapplication.exe" /a="\"I am passing this argument \n my newline\"";

But while executing, it discards the "my newline" as argument. In my application I need this new line as a new line to be passed as a text.

Is it possible to pass a new line character in a command line parameter.

Comment: can you little bit elaborate how you do with steps? @satyajit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to replicate your concern since you did not provide a valid sample code.

Here's a working code.

Program to display args:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach(string s in args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Program to start the process:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Process process = new Process();

            // Configure the process using the StartInfo properties.
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\tugadoje\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"I am passing this argument \n my newline\"";
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();// Waits here for the process to exit.

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: Working]